# Writing a python script, Can I do this with the random module?

Tags: python

I have to write a Code that prints out random dataset for a smart refrigerator.

Random Data for:

Energy usage range between 100 to 400 watts:

```
Example = 155 watts, 385 watts
```

Random model number like:

```
Example = model: "hs1234"
```

Temperature dataset range between 35° and 40°F

```
Example = 36, 37, 39.......
```

Comment: I recommend you try it for yourself. Here is the python docs on the random module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers. Then come back here if you have a *specific* question about your code.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but Python does in fact support random numbers through the use of the `random` library. Here is a link to a couple of examples using the random library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to produce totally random numbers within ranges, you can use randrange.

```
from random import randrange

temp_range = randrange(35,40)
energy_use = randrange(100,400)
model_number = randrange(1000,9999)

print(f"Random Energy Use: {energy_use} watts.")
print(f"Random Model Number: hs{model_number}")
print(f"Temperature: {temp_range}°F")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to ask for but you're saying "Can I do this with the random module?" and yes you can.

```
import random
import math

energy_low = 100 #watts
energy_high = 400 #watts

print(random.randint(energy_low, energy_high))
```